# MongoDB referenced collections. Create doesn't take effect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an application on express and Mongodb. I am using references for the first time.

As you can see below, studycat has a field called "studycatname" which is referenced in studyfieldsSchema.

```
//========== DATABASE ========================//
//SCHEMA SETUP 
var studyfieldsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    studycat: 
        {
            type:   mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "studycat"
        }
    ,
    fieldname:  String,  
    fieldtype:  String,  
    fieldinputtype: String
});
var studycatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    studycatname:   String
});

//MODEL SETUP - COMPILE THE ABOVE SCHEMA TO A MODEL
var studyfields = mongoose.model("studyfields", studyfieldsSchema);
var studycat = mongoose.model("studycat", studycatSchema);

//=============================================//
```

In the studyfields creation form (a ejs file), the right _ids are being displayed.

```
                        Category: 
                        <select name="catname">
                            <% studycats.forEach(function(studycatitem){ %>
                                <option value="<%= studycatitem._id %>"><%= studycatitem.studycatname %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                        </select>
```

When the form is submitted, i am expecting to the see that value "studycat" in the "studyfields" collection. but I don't.

here is my POST route:

```
app.post("/adminstudy", function(req, res){
    //console.log(req.body.study); //Shows parameters coming from the form. 
    var studycatname = req.body.catname;
    var fieldname = req.body.fieldname;
    var fieldtype = req.body.fieldtype;
    var fieldinputtype = req.body.fieldinputtype;
    var newstudyfield = {fieldname: fieldname, fieldtype: fieldtype,  fieldinputtype: fieldinputtype, studycatname: studycatname} // Tablefieldname: Formfieldname
    //create a new studyfield and save it to the database.
    studyfields.create(newstudyfield, function(err,newlycreated_sf){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            console.log(newstudyfield);
            console.log(newlycreated_sf);
            res.redirect("/adminstudy"); //redirects to GET route.
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't save it in the db.

Because you don't use the `save()` function of the model.

```
app.post("/adminstudy", function(req, res){
    //console.log(req.body.study); //Shows parameters coming from the form. 
    var studycatname = req.body.catname;
    var fieldname = req.body.fieldname;
    var fieldtype = req.body.fieldtype;
    var fieldinputtype = req.body.fieldinputtype;
    var newstudyfield = {fieldname: fieldname, fieldtype: fieldtype,  fieldinputtype: fieldinputtype, studycatname: studycatname} // Tablefieldname: Formfieldname
    //create a new studyfield and save it to the database.
    studyfields.create(newstudyfield, function(err,newlycreated_sf){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            console.log(newstudyfield);
            console.log(newlycreated_sf);
        }
    });
 studyfields.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.redirect("/adminstudy"); //redirects to GET route.
});
});
```

Or you can do :

```
/create a new studyfield and save it to the database.
        studyfields.create(newstudyfield, function(err,newlycreated_sf){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
                console.log(newstudyfield);
                console.log(newlycreated_sf);
                this.save(function(err)) {
                  if (err) return handleError(err);
                  res.redirect("/adminstudy"); //redirects to GET route.
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**

Alright i didn't get that,so if i get it right this time you re tying to do a populate or a join in sql ?

*first:*

```
var studyfieldsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    studycat: 
        {
            _id:   mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // _id and not type
            ref: "studycat"
        }
    ,
    fieldname:  String,  
    fieldtype:  String,  
    fieldinputtype: String
});
var studycatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    studycatname:   String
});
```

*second:*

You need to first use the find function to find the right studycat and put the id of this studycat in your create function :

```
var newstudyfield = {fieldname: fieldname, fieldtype: fieldtype,  fieldinputtype: fieldinputtype, studycatname: "HERE PUT THE ID OF THE STUDYCAT"} // Tablefieldname: Formfieldname
```

To get the right documents you need to use the [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) function to join the two models.

Let me know if this is not clear

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. My code saves all other fields except for the studycatname field.